# Optimizing slow push times for docker images in Google Artifact Registry through Cloud Build

Tags: google-cloud-platform, docker-registry, google-cloud-build, google-artifact-registry

When using Google Cloud Build in collaboration with the Google's Artifact Registry, we are seeing build times up to tens of minutes. Only a small segment of this time is spent on the actual "build" operation, and the rest (e.g. 1 minute to build -- 8 minutes to just push) is spent on pushing that artifact (which is a docker image with only a single changed layer) to the AR.

- The build operation has a single step, and that steps uses the google provided docker builder with the following image (and the image is not pushed directly but rather marked as an artifact to be pushed by Cloud Build automatically):

```
FROM python:3.9
RUN pip install $deps
CMD ["python", "-m", "something-something"]
```

- Both the Cloud Build builds (workers) and the Artifact Registry are in the same region (us-central1).
- For small layers, the operation is very negligible (in our use case, only the final layer changes and if that layer is 25MB then the push might take 20s; but if that layer is 4.5G, then the push takes like 6-7 minutes) which indicates there is no fixed overhead.
- The timings are directly taken from the Cloud Build's "build summary" page which splits the entire build into three phases: "Fetch source", "Build step(s)", "Push". Our problem is specifically related to the "Push" phase.
- Have tried both the default machine and bigger machines (e.g. e2-highcpu-8) for better network.

Answer (score 0):

If the layer is 4.5 GB and the push takes 7 minutes, then the transfer rate is `4.5 * 10^9 * 8 / (7 * 60) = 85.7 Mbit/sec`. That is a reasonable/good transfer speed.

Factor in the management overhead for Artifact Registry, data consistency, and transfer time an aggregate transfer speed of 85.7 Mbit/sec might be considered very good.

Your issue, which is the total time to upload, is not a problem. Your expectation is not realistic.

Answer (score 0):

This [document](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/optimize-builds/speeding-up-builds) provides the best practices for speeding up Cloud Build builds.

**Building leaner containers**

> To help reduce the size of your container image, separate the building of the application, along with the tools used to build it, from the assembly of the runtime container.

**Using Kaniko cache**

> In a container image registry, such as Google's own Container Registry, Kaniko cache, a Cloud Build feature, caches container build artifacts by storing and indexing intermediate layers so that later builds can utilise them.

**Using a cached Docker image**

> The easiest way to increase the speed of your Docker image build is by specifying a cached image that can be used for subsequent builds. You can specify the cached image by adding the --cache-from argument in your build config file, which will instruct Docker to build using that image as a cache source.

**Caching directories with Google Cloud Storage**

> To increase the speed of a build, reuse the results from a previous build. You can copy the results of a previous build to a Google Cloud Storage bucket, use the results for faster calculation, and then copy the new results back to the bucket

Answer (score 0):

Leveraging caching is one of the most effective ways to cut build times between cloudbuild and artefact registry. I had a build that would typically take ~20 mins cut to ~3 mins with correctly configured caching.

Not only does it save on build it also saves on push as existing layers do not need to be re-uploaeded (I did not expect this additional mechanism but I was pleasantly surprised).

Here's my implementation:

```yaml
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args: ['-c', 'docker pull {REGION}-docker.pkg.dev/$PROJECT_ID/{REPO}/{IMAGE}:latest || exit 0']
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: [
      'build',
      '-t',
      '{REGION}-docker.pkg.dev/$PROJECT_ID/{REPO}/{IMAGE}:$SHORT_SHA',
      '.', # change for your relevant build context
      '--cache-from', '{REGION}-docker.pkg.dev/$PROJECT_ID/{REPO}/{IMAGE}:latest'
]
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['tag', '{REGION}-docker.pkg.dev/$PROJECT_ID/{REPO}/{IMAGE}:$SHORT_SHA', '{REGION}-docker.pkg.dev/$PROJECT_ID/{REPO}/{IMAGE}:latest']
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['push', '{REGION}-docker.pkg.dev/$PROJECT_ID/{REPO}/{IMAGE}:$SHORT_SHA']
images:
- '{REGION}-docker.pkg.dev/$PROJECT_ID/{REPO}/{IMAGE}:$SHORT_SHA'
- '{REGION}-docker.pkg.dev/$PROJECT_ID/{REPO}/{IMAGE}:latest'
options:
  logging: CLOUD_LOGGING_ONLY
  machineType: 'E2_HIGHCPU_32'
```

Comment: This will not help with the OPs problem. He is building an image. Only the final layer is changing. If the changed image layer is 4.5 GB, no caching will change the time it takes to push the final layer. 4.5 GB will need to be pushed.

Comment: Sure, but with Python images, it's highly unlikely the final layer is 4.5gb if you've done your job right.


Best practices would dictate that you run your heavy dependency layers first and any code changes last, enabling you to leverage the benefits of caching. 9 times out of 10 your code changes (e.g. `COPY . .`) is super fast an results in a tiny layer.  

Perhaps the best advice here is to organise layers to leverage caching and lean towards scenarios where the layer is 25MB not 4.5GB.

Comment: However, the OP literally said: **but if that layer is 4.5G, then the push takes like 6-7 minutes**